# The account index does not exist in accountKeys?

Tags: transactions, transaction-instructions

I just started to get to know Solana and wanted to analyze a swap transaction, but I found that the number of the account exceeded the number of account keys in message.
Where can i found the Pubkey of the index?

---

For example, there are 17 pubkeys in accountKeys, the biggest index should be 16?
But in one of the instructions, there is an 29 index, where should i to find it's pubkey?

## accountKeys

```
"accountKeys": [
    "3eQ8GdG5FSLJX3YGXA7bjxo1hQogdbRvzzxEPMkih7e1",
    "3kZ5HVmpH67mnh7yUvTmaF9Nmj1pvVENqpf885iGtxBH",
    "3yDoHj1BYR9AdJ4zHwzJuUX1EpsQPfp8A4U2cnJtVMNw",
    "4XYBrh3Cdebjsf36iwP7fXbMbMN3xGTLkUraPu9zrccV",
    "7Ffz2X15pUQT9yn3ieQmqobzvHkb1gkqBKQp4PoEKSWP",
    "9KvcqqrTNY6FMhuJ9RXQQtZZnnC1CNBbTtGUX91gm9mT",
    "A8kEy5wWgdW4FG593fQJ5QPVbqx1wkfXw9c4L9bPo2CN",
    "EXrqY7jLTLp83H38L8Zw3GvGkk1KoQbYTckPGBghwD8X",
    "J2GZSP5CfPb2aJnL5dsKE4NbYRQwD66M1HDkk9MJBACf",
    "11111111111111111111111111111111",
    "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
    "JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4",
    "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
    "5jFnsfx36DyGk8uVGrbXnVUMTsBkPXGpx6e69BiGFzko",
    "9nnLbotNTcUhvbrsA6Mdkx45Sm82G35zo28AqUvjExn8",
    "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL",
    "D8cy77BBepLMngZx6ZukaTff5hCt1HrWyKk3Hnd9oitf"
]
```

## instrucion

```
{"programIdIndex":15,"accounts":[0,2,0,29,9,12],"data":"2","stackHeight":null},
```

I have reviewed the relevant documentation and speculate that it might be possible to check from the AddressLookupTable, but there seems to be no available SDK for Rust to query it.
If I got the address_table_lookups in tx's message, how could i do with it?. I tried to use get_program_accounts_with_config, but it returns [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're fetching this transaction with RPC's `getTransaction`, so you can check the `loadedAddresses` parameter in the `meta` of the result for the additional addresses that come from lookup tables.

You should be able to count up from the end of the `accountKeys`, through the `writable` loaded addresses, and then the `readonly` loaded addresses, which will give you the pubkey.

More info at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction